# How can I use the "this" keyword instead of an element Id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a web app in which I remove all elements from a `select`, using:

```
$('#State option').each(function(i, option){ $(option).remove(); });
```

How can I use the `this` keyword instead of '#State'?

From OP comment:
I have multiple drop down elements. When focusing it, I have to call one function which deletes all elements from currently selected drop down

Comment: why not just `$("#State option").remove()` ?

Comment: Agreed. If you want to understand where you would use 'this', it would just be in the selector in your function instead of option, but it's more straightforward code to just call it on the jquery object that already contains your selected options.

Comment: Well, but instead of State i want to use this keyword

Comment: What 'this' refers to is context dependent. Outside of the function passed to each, this would refer to something else, potentially the window object.

Comment: You need a valid selector to select any element, you cannot use this instead of State.

Comment: The value of a function's *this* keyword is set by the call. How do you call that bit of code?

Comment: I have mutiple drop down elements. When focusing it, I have to call one function which deletes all elements from currently selectd drop down

Comment: Then you likely have a focus listener. When taht listener is called, its *this* will be the element. You can remove all the options by doing `this.options.length = 0;`

Comment: you have multiple elements with the same id `State` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have multiple drop down elements. When focusing it, I have to call one function which deletes all elements from currently selected drop down.

I don't know if that's good UI design, but assuming it's needed...

```
//--- When any select is focused, this will remove all options from just that select.
$('select'). bind ("focus", function () {
    $(this).find ('option').remove ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're trying to ask.  You want to remove all the elements of EVERY drop down list on your page?  If that is the case, just use this code:

```
$('select option').remove();
```

You can use $(this) to reference very drop down list on iteration, but that is unnecessary for what you're trying to accomplish.  Below is the in-efficient method using $(this) and iteration:

```
$('select').each(function () { $(this).find('option').remove(); })
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative interpretation:

> How can i use this keyword instead of '#State'

In the following I'm assuming that you are already in a context where `this` refers to the DOM element with `id = State`. In that case,

```
$('option', this).each(function(i, option){ $(option).remove(); });
```

will be equivalent to:

```
$('#State option').each(function(i, option){ $(option).remove(); });
```

Here, we take advantage of the [`jQuery( selector, [context] )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) signature of `jQuery()`.